# solve two-dimensional nonlinear system numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Given the system $$x' = x(1 − y^2) \\ y' = y^2(1 − x^2)$$

I can plot the trajectories according to the analysis of its fixed points, but I need help with solving it numerically.

Can anyone help me with solving this system numerically?

Comment: Numerical solutions are generally obtained using software. It would be helpful to know what software tools you are familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x(1-y^2)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2(1-x^2)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2(1-x^2)}{x(1-y^2)}$$
$$\frac{1-y^2}{y^2}dy=\frac{1-x^2}{x}dx$$
After integration:
$$-\frac{1}{y}-y=\ln|x|-\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$y^2+(\ln|x|-\frac{x^2}{2}+c)y+1=0$$
$$y=\frac{ -(\ln|x|-\frac{x^2}{2}+c) \pm \sqrt{(\ln|x|-\frac{x^2}{2}+c)^2-4}}{2}$$
Then you can compute $y(x)$ numerically.

Example with numerical method :

Starting point : $(t=0,x=2,y=3)$

Final point : $t=1/2,x\simeq 0.167,y\simeq 3.55)$

[image]

Without computer, it is possible to compute approximates "by hand", but with lower accuracy.

Comment: Did you not read the question to mean "how do I use numerical methods to approximate the solution"? For example, find a decimal approximation of my location at time $1/2$ if I start at $(2,3)$.

Comment: Did you not read the judicious comment of Mark McClure ? Without your answer to his comment, no appropriate answer for you. My first answer was not for you, but for people interested in analytical solving of ODE systems.